# Twitter bot APIs are not working

Tags: api, twitter

Since yesterday, I'm facing an issue where, strangely, twitter APIs are working and sometimes not!

**Error:**

> Bad twitter streaming request: 410
>   The site streams and user streams endpoints have been turned off. Please migrate to alternate apis.

Is this only me or anyone else is facing this problem?

Comment: But it says "...been turned off. Please migrate to alternate apis."? Does that not answer your question?

Comment: https://twitter.com/TwitterAPI/status/1030122500561166336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [link](https://twittercommunity.com/t/details-and-what-to-expect-from-the-api-deprecations-this-week-on-august-16-2018/110746)

Twitter recently announced that they are shutting down some services and endpoints and, to force the developers to use new services and apis, they are flickering the apis periodically. (you can get more information of flicker in the above link)

So, you need to change(upgrade) your apis to avoid the issues you're facing right now.

Comment: Why answer the same thing as an existing answer _and_ an existing comment?

Comment: Earlier, I also had the same issue.and I was typing and unaware of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error message, the API has been deprecated.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/details-and-what-to-expect-from-the-api-deprecations-this-week-on-august-16-2018/110746